# How to rotate Ellipseselector widget in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, widget

I was following the matplotlib ellipseselector example here:[Matplotlib EllipseSelector - how to get the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229211/matplotlib-ellipseselector-how-to-get-the-path) to draw an mask/roi on an image.
But how do I rotate the ellipse around the center?
[see the image below, red lines]

[image]

For example `ellipse` take an argument called `angle` that rotates the ellipse around the center.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/ellipse_demo.html